# Animation with wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

In wxWidgets, is it possible to have on a wxPanel, an object that contains a mouse click event which moves the objects to another location when activated? The movement should be seen as an animation, e.g. Sliding from its initial location to the next location (Using wxTimer?). Is this by any means, possible?

Comment: This is a strange question. Of course it's possible, why wouldn't it be. You probably want/need to ask something more concrete about how to do whatever you're doing, but it's not clear at all what are you asking here.

Comment: I apologize for not making this clear enough. Here goes, do I have to use wxTimer to achieve this or are there any other alternate solution to this? I'm pretty sure wxOGL can achieve this easily but that is something I want to avoid using.

Comment: If you want to animate something, you do need to use `wxTimer`, yes. There is also `wxAnimationCtrl` but this doesn't seem to be the kind of animation you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try with wxTimer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to change the position of whatever you are displaying smoothly so a timer at 25 Hz and then update the position a proportion of the movement each time, e.g. if you need to move from 0,0 to 100,200 smoothly in 4 seconds then updating your position by +1,+2 each timer event should do nicely.  You may find that you need to invalidate a display area that includes the position before the move and after it to force a redraw but give it a try without first.